# Function return function taking parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to comprehend the following coding style

```
class A {
  constructor () {
    this.app.use(somefunc(a, b)) 
  }

  const somefunc = (docStore, workspaced = true) => {
   return (req, res, next) => {
  // Do something 
  } 

}
```

Here, Can someone explain me how is our return getting req, res and next? like how are we passing it?

When I am invoking the function, I am passing `a, b` to `someFunc` then how is the anonymous function receiving   `(req, res, next)`

Can someone please explain the execution order?

Comment: You're returning a anonymous function

Comment: @CodeManiac How is our anonymous function getting `(req, res, next)`?

Comment: These will be passed when you invoke the function,

Comment: First you need to create an object of `A` class like `const a = new A();` and then  you can use it like `a.somefunc(docStore, workspaced )(req, res, next);` or you can pass  like `a.somefunc(docStore, workspaced )` as express router's callback

Comment: How is `a.somefunc(docStore, workspaced )(req, res, next)` equal to `a.somefunc(docStore, workspaced )`? @ArifKhan

Comment: Both are not equal, that is just 2 different example to use it, provide code where you are using `somefunc`function

Comment: @ArifKhan In constructor  `this.app.use(somefunc(a, b))` that's the only place where this function is being used

Comment: `this.app` is an instance of express and you are using `somefunc` as a middleware function(`use`) hence `req, res, next` will be passed by express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `somefunc` called, returns a `function` as result.
In code below you can call `anotherfunc` like a function.

```
var anotherfunc = somefunc(a,b);
```

in your code you pass this `anotherfunc` to function `use`, so when `use` need to call it, should pass its arguments (req, res, next) to it.

Infact it gets its parameters (`req, res, next`) when someone calls it, and probably it has been called somewhere in body of `use` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
(req, res, next) => {
  // Do something 
  }
```

This is an anonymous arrow function and a function can take any parameters. The return is returning a function and the parameters are for the function and not for the return statement

Comment: how is our return statement getting `req, res, next`

Comment: @anny123 it's getting those when the returned function is called. req, res, and next are parameters to the function. So whatever calls the returned function will provide those 3.

Comment: @DawnMinion How is returned function being called in the above code snippet? I mean, I understand this code `const someNewFunc = somefunc(a, b); someNewFunc(req, res, next)` or `somefunc(docStore, workspaced )(req, res, next)`

Comment: You return another function. That is equivalent to asking, how is the following function get its paramaeters: `function (a, b) { // do something}` ?

Comment: @ellipsis, your answer is correct, but I believe you should give a practical example for the OP to understand, with the log outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> In mathematics and computer science, a higher-order function is a function that does at least one of the following:
>
> - takes one or more functions as arguments (i.e. procedural parameters)
> - returns a function as its result. (Wikipedia)

`somefunc` is returning a function. As simple as that.

```
var func = somefunc(docStore, workspaced);
func(req, res, next); // now you pass the parameters
```

You can also call it in one line `somefunc(docStore, workspaced)(req, res, next);`

edit: One thing to note here is that docStore and workspaced are available for use in the returned function.

Answer (score 1):

You anonymous function returns a function and `app.use` calls it, now when using the arrow function you can chain them in two ways as below, if you are chaining as `foo(bar)` then the arguments passed to the first functions will be passed further.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let test = (x, y, z) => console.log(x, y, z);
arr.map(test);
arr.map((e, i, array) => test(e, i, array))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to explain this is with another example:

Here's a function `adder`. It allows you to create new adding functions.

It accepts an argument `a` and returns a new function. The returned function (a closure - a function that has access to its outer lexical environment) accepts an argument `b` and - *when it is called* - returns the sum of `a` and `b`.

We assign the result of calling `adder` (which is a function) to `addTwo`. We then call `addTwo` with an argument (`b`) which returns the value of `a + b`.

```js
function adder(a) {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

const addTwo = adder(2);
const result = addTwo(2);
console.log(result);
```